# Past tense and simultaneous events: do you use two Past Progressive or two Past Simple?

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

I was told that for two simultaneous events occurring in the past, you *should* use Past Progressive, such as:

> "While I was setting the table, she was cooking dinner."

But that two Past Simple events was acceptable colloquially, such as:

> "While I set the table, she cooked dinner."

But I don't understand why one is preferred over the other (and why the second one would be considered colloquial) and feel like there is a difference in meaning between the two that would make the Past Simple version preferable in some contexts.

What is the difference in usage between these two examples? When would one be preferred other the other, if at all?

Comment: Both seem equally acceptable to me. Indeed, since I assume cooking dinner would take longer than setting the table, you could also say "I set the table while she was cooking the dinner".

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting, they're both OK conversationally.   One reason you might want to prefer the first form is that the second one is ambiguous:  it can have the meaning of the first form, or it could be using `while` to distinguish two different activities or attributes, as in "While some horses are black, others are brown."   In that case it would not be necessary that the two actions were placed in time or happened strictly simultaneously.  It's difficult to imagine a context in which this ambiguity is a problem, however.

Comment: I might have chosen the wrong example- let's say both events take the same amount of time such as 'While I was reading my book, she was reading her book' and 'While I read my book, she read her book.' Rather than the content, I'm curious as to when or why two past progressive/continuous phrases might be the preferred or more grammatically correct choice to two past simple phrases. @BadZen makes a good point about the ambiguity of 'while' in this example as well.

Comment: Just as in any language, use and grammar norms are fluid, and constantly changing.  This is what some linguists mean when they say things like "use is language".   As a result, here are a lot of "rules" that grammar books and language classes teach that don't really always strictly apply to conversation.  "Don't split infinitives", "don't end a sentence with a preposition", the 'correct' use of "whom", and many other "rules" can be learned and were in some sense "orthodox" in previous times, but are not really heeded by English speakers everyday anymore.   This is one of those.